# Keeping my out bound IPs on App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, reserved-ip-addresses

I have a website on Azure App service and I've asked a service provider to open up for my outbound IP addresses. How can I make sure that those IPs won't change?

If there is a new IP assigned to my app service, all calls from that IP will be blocked by the service provider.

Answer (score 1):

The outbound IP addresses are per stamp/scale unit that the apps are on. It is not specific to a certain webspace or resource group.
You can find the stamp/scale unit in the Properties blade under the FTP Hostname endpoint. It should list out something like "waws-prod--". All of the apps in the same stamp/scale unit number in that region will have the same outbound IP addresses, as they are per stamp/scale unit.

The list of outbound IP addresses is not completely static but normally it does not change. Check out the reasons for the IP change in the thread outlined by Ruslan.

If you need both incoming and outgoing to be static, you will need an App Service Environment. This will give you dedicated IP addresses. 
For more information see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-app-service-environment-intro and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt793270.aspx.